# React Switch Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this simple react component for my switch button , all want is to set my true and false active  state when I click or toggle it , maybe display a console that barista or cafe owner is active

[Use Link inside my code to view Switch button gif][1]

```
import React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";

export default class Switch extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            active: true,
        }   
    }
    render() {
        const { active } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <label className="switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn" ></input>
                    <div className="slider round">

                        <span className="Cafe_Owner">Cafe Owner</span>
                        <span className="Barista">Barista</span>

                    </div>
                </label>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyG6b.gif
```

Comment: Can you explain more, what is your question here?

Comment: Basically I want to run a check to see what I have switched to between Cafe Owner and Barista                        here is a gif for visualation 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyG6b.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code for my solution

```
import React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";

export default class Switch extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            active: true,
        }  
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this) 
    }
        handleClick() {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            active: !prevState.active
        }))
      }
    render() {
        const { active } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <label className="switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn" ></input>
                    <div className="slider round" onClick={this.handleClick}>

                        <span className="Cafe_Owner">Cafe Owner</span>
                        <span className="Barista">Barista</span>

                    </div>
                </label>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```